# How do i upgrade the council through a runtime Upgrade?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, nodes

I have written code for a storage migration but unfortunately the council members are not displaying after the runtime upgrade. Below is the code I wrote for the storage migration

```rs
const COUNCIL_PREFIX: &str = "Instance1Council";

pub struct CouncilStoragePrefixMigration;

impl OnRuntimeUpgrade for CouncilStoragePrefixMigration {
    fn on_runtime_upgrade() -> frame_support::weights::Weight {
        pallet_collective::migrations::v4::migrate::<Runtime, Council, _>(COUNCIL_PREFIX)
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
    fn pre_upgrade() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
        pallet_collective::migrations::v4::pre_migrate::<Council, _>(COUNCIL_PREFIX);
        Ok(())
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
    fn post_upgrade() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
        pallet_collective::migrations::v4::post_migrate::<Council, _>(COUNCIL_PREFIX);
        Ok(())
    }
}

type Migrations = (
    CouncilStoragePrefixMigration,
);
```

I also updated the `spec_version` but after the runtime upgrade the council members don't show up. How can I implement the storage migration correctly? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what's the content of `pallet_collective::migrations::v4::migrate::`.